# getting average of top 3 grades in 2d array in c++

Tags: c++

I have written sorting code . But I just want to ask if is there any way to get average of top 3 grades in totally 4 grades in 2d array.
Or the sorting is best way??

Comment: If there are only 4 grades, find the lowest one and kick it out is also a way to achieve.

Comment: See [`std::partial_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort).

Comment: Currently your question is misunderstood to only focus on 4 grades, without considering the special way of storing it in a 2d array. Surely the data structure is relevant for your question, otherwise why mention it in the title. You need hence to elaborate its signigificance or the core of your question remains unclear. I.e., without more information, the answer seems to be the comment by @LouisGo